# Internal Debug needed, Runtime error 1004 Excel VBA Search Box Filter

Tags: excel, vba

[Edited]

I am attempting to get a running searchbar on an excel file. The reason for this is to make it user friendly. Expected results is using radio buttons, typing in a keyword and having it only pull up/filter to that result.

[Excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOMP7.png)

Here is the error I keep getting no matter what I change.
[ErrorCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFTuT.png)

Code:

```
Sub SearchBox()
'PURPOSE: Filter Data on User-Determined Column & Text
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim myButton As OptionButton
Dim MyVal As Long
Dim ButtonName As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim myField As Long
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim mySearch As Variant
  
'Load Sheet into A Variable
  Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Unfilter Data (if necessary)
  On Error Resume Next
    sht.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0
  
'Filtered Data Range (include column heading cells)
  'Set DataRange = sht.Range("A6:Y1000") 'Cell Range
  Set DataRange = sht.ListObjects("Sheet1").Range 'Table

'Retrieve User's Search Input
  mySearch = Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.Text 'Control Form
  'mySearch = sht.OLEObjects("UserSearch").Object.Text 'ActiveX Control
  'mySearch = sht.Range("A1").Value 'Cell Input

'Loop Through Option Buttons
  For Each myButton In ActiveSheet.OptionButtons
      If myButton.Value = 1 Then
        ButtonName = myButton.Text
        Exit For
      End If
  Next myButton
  
'Determine Filter Field
  On Error GoTo HeadingNotFound
    myField = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ButtonName, DataRange.Rows(1), 0)
  On Error GoTo 0
  
'Filter Data
      DataRange.AutoFilter _
    Field:=myField, _
    Criteria1:="=*" & mySearch & "*", _
    Operator:=xlAnd
  
'Clear Search Field
  Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.Text = "" 'Control Form
  'sht.OLEObjects("UserSearch").Object.Text = "" 'ActiveX Control
  'sht.Range("A6").Value = "" 'Cell Input

Exit Sub

    'ERROR HANDLERS
HeadingNotFound:
      MsgBox "The column heading [" & ButtonName & "] was not found in cells " & DataRange.Rows(1).Address & ". " & _
        vbNewLine & "Please check for possible typos.", vbCritical, "Header Name Not Found!"
        
End Sub
```

I have adjusted this code a few times and believe it makes sense logically. I feel like it only needs minor debugging to work, but I do not understand what to change to get over runtime error 1004. It may have something to do with the assigned textbox I have but I do not understand vba or excel enough to know what to alter.

Does anyone who understands excel/vba enough willing to debug this for me?

[Filebin of Excel + Broken Macro](https://filebin.net/zm9420cp6lfhx00s)

Comment: No screenshots of code. Please [edit] your question with the code as text. See [ask] and [reprex] and maybe take the [tour] as well.

Comment: And note that no one want's to download and open an Macro-enabled Excel file from an unknown source. For a good reason.

Comment: You'd need to share a download link, not a "view" link: it's not possible to download the complete files from there (some "unsupported features" are removed).   It's possible the column header Match step failed: that would be a problem for the autofilter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

It's awkward to have to use the exact column header for the option button text, so there's a function to map between the two.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SearchBox()
   
    Dim myButton As OptionButton
    'Dim MyVal As Long
    Dim header As String
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    'Dim myField As Long
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Dim mySearch As Variant, m, optText
      
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    
    With sht.ListObjects("Table1")
        Set DataRange = .Range
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End With
    
    mySearch = Trim(ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Text)
    If Len(mySearch) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'no search term
    
    For Each myButton In sht.OptionButtons
        If myButton.Value = 1 Then
          optText = myButton.Text
          Exit For
        End If
    Next myButton
    
    header = GetHeader(optText) 'map option button to a column
    If Len(header) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Could not map option button text '" & optText & "' to column header"
        Exit Sub
    End If
      
    m = Application.Match(header, DataRange.Rows(1), 0) 'no WorksheetFunction
    If Not IsError(m) Then
        DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=m, Criteria1:="=*" & mySearch & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
    Else
        'm is an error value, so there was no match
        MsgBox "The column heading [" & header & "] was not found in cells " & DataRange.Rows(1).Address & ". " & _
                vbNewLine & "Please check for possible typos.", vbCritical, "Header Name Not Found!"
    End If
   
End Sub

'Map your option button text to a column header in your table
'  so you can use different text for your option buttons
Function GetHeader(optText)
    Select Case optText
        Case "School email": GetHeader = "Enter your group member's school email you are evaluating."
        Case "Name": GetHeader = "Name"
        Case "Class code": GetHeader = "What is the class code this is for? (ex: INFO SCI 410)"
    End Select
End Function
```